# Getting Run-time error '3706' error while connecting to Oracle DB using VBA in excel

Tags: oracle, excel, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB for the first time using the ODBC Datasource Connector(named Demo_DSN) When I Step Into (F8) the code is giving Run-time error '3706': application-defined or object -defined error

```
Sub ConnectToOracle()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet
    Dim mtxdata As Variant

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connnection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    cn.Open ( _
    "User ID = XXGMDMADM" & _
    ";Password=xxgmdmadmdb" & _
    ";Data Source= Demo_DSN" &_
    ";Provider= OraOLEDB.Oracle")

    'Cleanup in the end
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: VB Script IsNot VB.NET AndAlso IsNot VBA.  Read [ask] and take the [tour] and consult the tag usage guidance text on the tags you chose.

Comment: Is the OLEDB Oracle Provider installed?